# Refactor jQuery to vanila JS to make a custom select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a custom select with some jQuery code that i cant convert to pure JavaScript

https://codepen.io/PeterGeller/pen/wksIF

Based on the codePen i tried with 3 selects.

```js
const select = document.getElementsByClassName('select-box');

const label1 = document.getElementById("S1");
const label2 = document.getElementById("S2");
const label3 = document.getElementById("S3");

const obj1 = document.getElementById('select-box1');
const obj2 = document.getElementById('select-box2');
const obj3 = document.getElementById('select-box3');

select[0].classList.add('open');    

if (obj1 !== null)
{
    const x = obj1.value;
    label1.value=x;
   $(select).removeClass('open');
}

if( obj2 !== null)
{
    const y = obj2.value;
    label2.value=y;
    $(select).removeClass('open');
}

if(obj3 !== null)
{
    const z = obj3.value;
    label3.value=z;
    $(select).removeClass('open');
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);

body {
  background: #ffffff; 
  color: #414141;
  font: 400 17px/2em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.select-box {
  cursor: pointer;
  position : relative;
  max-width:  20em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.select,
.label {
  color: #414141;
  display: block;
  font: 400 17px/2em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.select {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  background: none transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}
.select-box1 {
  background: #ececec;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.open .label::after {
   content: "▲";
}
.label::after {
  content: "▼";
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="select-box">
<label id="S1" class="label select-box1" for="select-box1">
    <span class="label-desc">Choose a color</span>
</label>
<select id="select-box1" className="select">
    <option value="1">red</option>
    <option value="2">green</option>
</select>

<label id="S2" class="label select-box1" for="select-box2">
    <span class="label-desc">Choose a letter</span>
</label>

<select id="select-box2" className="select">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>

<label id="S3" class="label select-box1" for="select-box3">
    <span class="label-desc">Choose a number</span>
</label>
<select id="select-box3" className="select">
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

</div>
```

What I'm missing to this code to work?

I need to change the value of the labels, add the class `open` when the mouse is on select and remove `open` when the value is not null.

Comment: So where are the event listeners? That code only runs when the page is loaded.

Comment: Also `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements not a single element. `classList` only exists on individual elements not the collection

Comment: Suggest you get this working with only one select. Then once it works for one try implementing on others. jQuery methods loop over collections under the hood to do same process to each instance

Comment: And check errors in dev tools console. Native elements have no `removeClass()` and should throw error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const selectBox = document.querySelector('.select-box')
select.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  selectBox.classList.toggle("open");

}); 

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e)
{
    if (!selectBox.contains(e.target)) {
        selectBox.classList.remove("open");
    }
});


select.addEventListener("change" , function(e) {
  const label = selectBox.querySelector('label');
  const selection = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  label.querySelector(".label-desc").innerHTML = selection;
    
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);

body {
  background: #ffffff; 
  color: #414141;
  font: 400 17px/2em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.select-box {
  cursor: pointer;
  position : relative;
  max-width:  20em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.select,
.label {
  color: #414141;
  display: block;
  font: 400 17px/2em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.select {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  background: none transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}
.select-box1 {
  background: #ececec;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.open .label::after {
   content: "▲";
}
.label::after {
  content: "▼";
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
 
  <div class="select-box">
    
    <label for="select-box1" class="label select-box1"><span class="label-desc">Choose your country</span> </label>
    <select id="select-box1" class="select">
      <option value="Choice 1">Falkland Islands</option>
      <option value="Choice 2">Germany</option>
      <option value="Choice 3">Neverland</option>
    </select>
    
  </div>
   
</form>
```

Here you go

https://codepen.io/itamarshdev/pen/JjELzPW?editors=1111

Comment: thanks so much, this code works like the original, with this code I can apply to my code and learn how to toggle multiple events with native javascript